# Where does Tomcat configure context path for examples webapp?

Tags: java, tomcat

I cannot find any declaration in server.xml for the "examples" webapp that is installed by default in Tomcat.

So where is the xml fragment in which this declaration had been done if not in server.xml ?

Comment: do you want to make your own project the default one instead of the example from tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Examples" is just one of various web applications deployed under Tomcat that loads web applications from folder "webapps" located under `$CATALINA_BASE`. This location is configured in `server.xml`, in tag "Host":

```
  <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

and can be changed if it is needed.